# How to design calculation API in RESTFul way?

Tags: rest

I'm trying to design an API to calculate a result based on inputs.

**Real business**:

The API compares two securities portfolios (source and target) and return the orders, the consumer gets the orders, so he/she can then places those orders to adjust portfolio from source to target.

If this is hard to be understood, then here's a **similar scenario**:

The API compare two text, then return the difference of the 2 texts.

It is a little bit different from the classic CRUD, because the **inputs** and **output** are **different resources**

My first thought is like this:

```
POST /api/difference
{
    'source': { ... },
    'target': { ... }
}
```

But, it will be conflict with the classic payload:

```
POST /api/difference
{
    'lineNumber': ...,
    'isAdded': ...
}
```

Questions:

1. Should I use a media-type to distinguish the the input payloads? What a 'resource' should be in this case?
2. What should the API look like if I also want to place the orders (or apply the text diff) in the same time when the API is called?

Answer (score 0):

Iam not sure whether I understand your problem correctly, but in general it 
depends on whether the resources are already persisted in the system. In case 
both resources are already available in the system I would simply build an URI 
like `/portfolio/{source_id}/difference/{target_id}` which returns the diff 
result. If only the source exists I would probably use something like:

```
POST /portfolio/{source_id}/difference

{target}
```

If both resources are not available I would probably consider to first persist
such a resource and make then the comparison.

Comment: The source portfolio is the current portfolio of user's account. The target portfolio might have different total value, but will be adjusted to same total value before comparing and generating orders.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, there already exists the resource `POST /api/difference` and hence you are looking to change MIME type. Instead, why don't you go with the first approach and change the resource name? For example,

```
POST /api/compare
{
    'source': { ... },
    'target': { ... }
}
```